# Nodejs AWS Textract does not work on lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am using NodeJS AWS SDK textract for detecting image (image file dot PNG/JPG). It was working on AWS EC2. But it does not work in an AWS Lambda function.

There is response I get:

```
    {
        "err": {
            "message": "Request has unsupported document format",
            "code": "UnsupportedDocumentException",
            "time": "2019-12-07T08:49:52.788Z",
            "requestId": "fbd1cab5-d725-4f79-ac15-1f033e82aa79",
            "statusCode": 400,
            "retryable": false,
            "retryDelay": 37.87986431208581
        },
        "stack": "UnsupportedDocumentException: Request has unsupported document format\n    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)\n    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the sample code that works on EC2 but fails on Lambda so as to assist you better?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like lambda is not invoke with JSON event, two possible reasons,

Better to show how you invoke the lambda

**InvalidRequestContentException**

```
The request body could not be parsed as JSON.

HTTP Status Code: 400
```

**UnsupportedMediaTypeException**

```
The content type of the Invoke request body is not JSON.

HTTP Status Code: 415
```

[Lambda-API_Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

[handle-errors-in-lambda-integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html)